# SQL Query: AVG & MEAN of all rows of columns in row-wise

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 10 mark columns like below:

```
 S_ID   S_Name  MARK1   MARK2   MARK3
   1    TEST    50        60    70
   2    TEST_!  40        50    40
```

I need to write query to return AVG, MEAN, MEDIA of each marks in below format

```
SUB     MEAN    AVG   MEDIAN    STD   MIN   MAX
MARK1                       
MARK2                       
MARK3
```

below query return each passed column in column wise, but i need each column (MARKS) in row wise, accompanied by aggregation/calculation in column.

```
select min(mark1), max(mark1) from  student;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `UNPIVOT` your data into separate rows and then aggregate.

If you just `UNPIVOT`, you get this:

```
WITH test_data ( S_ID, S_Name,  MARK1,   MARK2,   MARK3) AS (
SELECT 1, 'TEST',    50,  60,  70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,' TEST_!',  40,  50,  40 FROM DUAL )
SELECT *
FROM test_data
UNPIVOT ( mark_value FOR mark_number IN ( MARK1, MARK2, MARK3 ) )
```

> ```
> +------+---------+-------------+------------+
> | S_ID | S_NAME  | MARK_NUMBER | MARK_VALUE |
> +------+---------+-------------+------------+
> |    1 | TEST    | MARK1       |         50 |
> |    1 | TEST    | MARK2       |         60 |
> |    1 | TEST    | MARK3       |         70 |
> |    2 |  TEST_! | MARK1       |         40 |
> |    2 |  TEST_! | MARK2       |         50 |
> |    2 |  TEST_! | MARK3       |         40 |
> +------+---------+-------------+------------+
> ```

From there, you just need to `GROUP BY` and compute your aggregates, so this would be the final query you'd need:

```
SELECT mark_number, 
       avg(mark_value) as mean,
       median(mark_value) as median,
       stddev(mark_value) as std,
       min(mark_value) as min,
       max(mark_value) as max
FROM test_data
UNPIVOT ( mark_value FOR mark_number IN ( MARK1, MARK2, MARK3 ) )
group by mark_number
```

> ```
> +-------------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------+-----+-----+
> | MARK_NUMBER | MEAN | MEDIAN |                    STD                    | MIN | MAX |
> +-------------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------+-----+-----+
> | MARK1       |   45 |     45 |  7.07106781186547524400844362104849039285 |  40 |  50 |
> | MARK2       |   55 |     55 |  7.07106781186547524400844362104849039285 |  50 |  60 |
> | MARK3       |   55 |     55 | 21.21320343559642573202533086314547117854 |  40 |  70 |
> +-------------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------+-----+-----+
> ```

And you're done.

Answer (score 2):

In MS SQL it can be acheived by unpivot.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE 
  ( 
     s_id   INT, 
     s_name VARCHAR(50), 
     mark1  INT, 
     mark2  INT, 
     mark3  INT 
  )

INSERT INTO @table
    VALUES (1, 'TEST', 50, 60, 70),
    (2, 'TEST_1', 40, 50, 40),
    (3, 'TEST_3', 20, 70, 80)

SELECT
    dtls
   ,SUM(sname) AS [SUM]
   ,AVG(sname) AS [AVG]
   ,STDEV(sname) AS [STD]
   ,MIN(sname) AS [MIN]
   ,MAX(sname) AS [MAX]
FROM @table
UNPIVOT (sname
FOR dtls IN (mark1,
mark2,
mark3)) AS unp
GROUP BY dtls
```

**[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/GUDKN6232)**

Comment: In Oracle it's similar: [dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4a6fb9da16310e7c4eb303dc90014bff).

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the aggregated columns for each SUB and also a column having a static value stating the SUB and union them all.

```
    SELECT 'MARK1' as SUB,AVG(mark1) as MEAN,MEDIAN(mark1) as MEDIAN,  min(mark1) as MIN, max(mark1) as MAX from student
    UNION
    SELECT 'MARK2' as SUB,AVG(mark2) as MEAN, MEDIAN(mark2) as MEDIAN,  min(mark2) as MIN, max(mark2) as MAX from student
    UNION
    SELECT 'MARK3' as SUB,AVG(mark3) as MEAN, MEDIAN(mark3) as MEDIAN,  min(mark3) as MIN, max(mark3) as MAX from student
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by unpivoting the data and then doing a single aggregation.

The following works in all versions of Oracle:

```
select sub,
       avg(mark1) as mean, median(mark1) as median,
       min(mark1) as min, max(mark1) as max
from ((select 'mark1' as sub, mark1 as mark from student
      ) union all
      (select 'mark2' as sub, mark1 as mark from student
      ) union all
      (select 'mark3' as sub, mark1 as mark from student
      )
     ) m
group by sub;
```

In Oracle 12C+, I would use a lateral join to unpivot the data.

This makes it easy to add new statistics -- say, the number of marks that exceed 90 -- for all three columns.